# Is it possible to isolate a network device from the rest of the LAN via its MAC address ?

Tags: local-area-network, mac-address

Is it possible to isolate a network device from the rest of the LAN via its MAC address ?

Im familiar with creating a VLAN based on a tagged port of the network switch, but is it possible by recognising the devices MAC address ?

Comment: If using (certain) Cisco devices you can implement MAC address based Access Control Lists. I don't know about other brands but I'm assuming they have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MAC based vLANs are possible. It depends on your switch's capabilities. You create a MAC address to vLAN map.

Here's an example of a Netgear and Cisco has it too, as well as many others I'm sure.

https://kb.netgear.com/21586/What-is-a-MAC-based-VLAN-and-how-does-it-work-with-my-managed-switch

Comment: Thanks @Appleoddity would it depend on the switch or the router ? We tend to have a mix of netgear switches and draytek routers

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it depends on.

Comment: The isolation must be an the uplink device the MAC is connected to, most likely that's the switch.

Comment: Thanks Zac. I think I misunderstood the question. Yes, it is configured on whatever device the computer plugs in to.